# Acer predator laptop dropping hdmi

Tags: laptop, hdmi

I have an Acer predator laptop, very lightly used, well maintained. It has an issue with keeping a continuous signal to an external monitor through HDMI. I have tried it with two different brand monitors, and with my insignia 55" TV. The monitors may drop anywhere between 5 and 10 minutes in, and I was lucky to get 30 seconds on the TV. When the monitor is also selected as the audio player, the sound will stop, but not revert back to the laptop when the video stops.

Comment: Have you also tried different cables?

Comment: @flolilolilo Yes, I've tried 3 different cables. essentially unplugging them from different sources that were already working on each individual monitor I tried

Comment: Have you checked for BIOS-updates (on my Acer TravelMate, which is probably absolutely unrelated to your notebook, there was a BIOS update which was described by Acer as "improving stability of HDMI" (or something along that)), have you checked for GPU-driver-updates? If you've done all of that, I would think that it's most likely the fault of the Acer's HDMI-connector. Or maybe you have to insert it "harder" - on my TravelMate, it feels as if the HDMI-plug is right in even if it's only half-way there.